# How to correctly configure put() options to receive progress events from Angular 6 HttpClient request?

Tags: angular

I would like to upload a file using HttpClient and report user about progress. Usually (without progress) I do it an a such way:

```
  this._http.put(url, file, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders() // some custom headers instead
    }).subscribe(() => {
        // uploaded
    }, (err) => {
        // failed
    });
```

So I pass some custom headers in options. According to sources there is possibility to set "reportProgress" flag in options, so I thought that this should work:

```
  this._http.put(url, file, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders() // some custom headers instead
      reportProgress: true
    }).subscribe(() => {
        // progress
    }, (err) => {
        // failed
    }, () => {
        // upload finished
    });
```

Unfortunately, this was not the case since put() method has a lot of overloads and by default returning

```
Observable<HttpResponse>
```

is used instead of returning

```
Observable<HttpEvent<Object>>
```

which looks like the one I need.
The problem is that I don't understand how to configure options object to call the correct method since "observe" field of it is not a string but a type, so I need options object with "observe" field of "events" type. How to do it? According to offical doc the progress can be get by using HttpInterceptor by I don't understand why I should created additional interceptor class if it looks like correctly configured put() method should already perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal complete solution based on doc examples modification:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpEventType } from "@angular/common/http";
import { map, tap, last } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class FileUploadService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  }

  upload(url: string, file: File, progress: (percent: number) => void, result: (success: boolean) => void) {
    const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', url, file, {
      reportProgress: true
    });

    this._http.request(req).pipe(
      map(event => this._getProgress(event)),
      tap(value => progress(value)),
      last()
    ).subscribe(() => {
      result(true);
    }, (err) => {
      result(false);
    });
  }

  private _getProgress(event: HttpEvent<any>) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Sent:
        return 0;
      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        return Math.round(10000 * event.loaded / event.total) / 100;
      case HttpEventType.Response:
        return 100;
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you know a solution using properly configured _http.put() only